# Have EntityFramework respect mysql max_user_connections

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-web-api2

Is there a way to tell Entity Framework to wait if max_user_connections connections are already open?

I guess I could catch the Exception and retry or keep a counter but that feels hacky at best.

My Azure logs are filling up with the following message:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 
Authentication to host 'xxx' for user 'yyy' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: 
User 'yyy' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 4)
```

I tried adding `Max Pool Size=4` to the connection string but that didn't help.

```
<add name="DbContext" connectionString="Database=db;Data Source=xxx;User Id=yyy;Password=zzz;CharSet=utf8;Persist Security Info=True;Convert Zero Datetime=True;Max Pool Size=4" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Comment: `max_user_connections` is a database parameter, so EF can't know about it before logging in. I believe the best you can do is catch the exception and handle it.

Comment: I do know the `max_user_connections` per environment. Any way I can tell EF to not open more connections?

Comment: You could manage this as a parameter and handle it in the context constructor but it'd be quite troublesome to sync this value across all instances of your application. I believe the best way is catching that exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Vito's suggestion: catch the exception and have the frontend decide what to do:

On the backend, I used [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/), an implementation of [Aspect-Oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) for .NET. It allows me to decorate all my Repositories with an attribute to handle this specific exception.

On the frontend I will probably do something like waiting for 400ms and trying again 1-3 times before giving up.

In the Package Manager Console:
`Install-Package PostSharp`

You also need to install a [PostSharp plugin for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a058d5d3-e654-43f8-a308-c3bdfdd0be4a)

```
[Serializable]
public class MaxMysqlConnectionExceptionHandlerAspect : OnExceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Exception.InnerException != null && args.Exception.InnerException.Message.Contains("Too many connections"))
        {
            args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.ThrowException;
            args.Exception = new Exception("MAX_CONNECTIONS");
        }
    }

    public override Type GetExceptionType(MethodBase method)
    {
        return typeof(EntityException);
    }
}
```

Then decorate the classes or methods:

```
[MaxMysqlConnectionExceptionHandlerAspect]
public class FancyPantsService {}
```